# How do I allow a function to be called when two spinners equal specific strings?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I have made 2 spinners, which both consist of an array of different types of weight. These are "lbs" "Stone" "Grams" "Kilograms". I need to be able to check the options the user has picked from these 2 spinners and then call a function depending on what they chose. So for example if the first spinner equals "Lbs" and the second equals "Grams", then a function will be called.

These are my strings

```
  <string-array name="weightFSpinner">
    <item>Lbs</item>
    <item>Grams</item>
    <item>Kilograms</item>
    <item>Stone</item>
    <item>Ounces</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="weightSSpinner">
    <item>Lbs</item>
    <item>Grams</item>
    <item>Kilograms</item>
    <item>Stone</item>
    <item>Ounces</item>
</string-array>
```

And this is the code on my weight page

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weight_page);
        // Code for first drop down list
        final Spinner weightFSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.weightFSpinner);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(weightPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weightFSpinner));
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        weightFSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);


        // code for second drop down list
        final Spinner weightSSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.weightSSpinner);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(weightPage.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weightSSpinner));
        myAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        weightSSpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter2);



        Button convertBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convertBtn);
        convertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            //when the button is pressed this happens
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(myAdapter.equals("Lbs") && myAdapter2.equals("Grams")){
                    poundsToGrams();
                }


            }

            //converting pounds to grams
            private void poundsToGrams() {
                EditText convertTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.convertTxt);
                TextView resultTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTxt);
                String firstWeight;
                String secondWeight;
                double pounds;

                try {
                    pounds = parseDouble(convertTxt.getText().toString());

                } catch
                        (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    convertTxt.setError("Must be int");
                    return;
                }
                double result = (pounds * 453.59237);
                resultTxt.setText(result + " Grams");
            }


            // firstWeight = myAdapter.getItem(0);
            //secondWeight = myAdapter2.getItem(1);


        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you can always use a button to call your function, otherwise I suggest you add a listener to your two spinners and after the user chose his weights, the function will be automatically called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following ways:

1: You could share the adapter between different Spinners if they adapted the same information. 
A single OnItemSelectedListener will work for the 2 Spinners. You can call **getId()** on the **AdapterView** passed as an argument to know which Spinner raised the event.

```
 @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

    switch(parentView.getId()){
        case R.id.weightFSpinner:
            fValue= weightFSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
        case R.id.weightSSpinner:
            sValue= weightSSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
        case ...
    }


}
```

2: Store the selected values in 2 variables item is selected from spinners.

3: then check the values of variables in click listener of button

Comment: I like this answer :)

Comment: The first part helped me solve this, thank you so much for your time

Comment: @barrelmp thanks for the feedback. It will be kind if you accept the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the .onItemSelectedListener listener to both the spinners and override its functions onNothingSelected and onItemSelected.

In the onItemSelected for both the spinners, save the value at the position to strings that is accessible to both spinners. For example, save weight from weightSSpinner to a string "myWeightS", and weight from weightFSpinner to a string "myWeightF".

Then in the onItemSelected function of both the spinners, check if the strings are equal. If they are, execute your desired function.

```
if(myWeightS.equals(myWeightF))
{
    //execute desired function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onItemSelectedListener to your spinner

```
     weightFSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(
                    new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        public void onItemSelected(
                                AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

// here you can add the if clauses to check which spinner contains which value and call the method accordingly 


                        }

                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                        }
                    });
```